# How to output the elements inside of each bins in ggplot stat_binhex()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a stat_binhex graph in R. My code is below.

```
stat_binhex(mapping = aes(x=longitude, y=latitude), 
          data = origin_latlng, 
          color = 'white',
          alpha=0.75,
          geom = "hex", 
          position = "identity", 
          bins = 25,
          na.rm=TRUE)    
stat_binhex(mapping = aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, label = ..count.., fill = {print(sum(..count..))}), 
          data = origin_latlng, 
          color = 'white',
          alpha=0.75,
          geom = "text", 
          size = 3,
          position = "identity", 
          hjust = 0.5,
          vjust = -0.3,
          bins = 25,
          na.rm=TRUE)
```

origin_latlng is a data.frame of coordinates. I want to output all coordinates are inside each of hex bins. I dont know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Save your ggplot to a variable (e.g. `gg`). Use `ggplot_build(gg)` to get the build object. The polygon centers will be in `gb$data[[1]]` (`x` & `y`) columns.  That only gets you the centers, but there should be enough info there to help you compute the hexagon corners. Use that info to build `Polygons` & then `SpatialPolygons` and use `point.in.polygon` using points from your original data the polygons you just built. ggplot2 calls `hexbin` and that pkg has no convenience methods to reverse engineer polygons (it makes `grid` polygons directly). https://github.com/edzer/hexbin for `hexbin src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made it. As what 'hrbrmstr' comments, use ggplot_build(graph) to build hexgon object and extract info in it. latlng of centroids are inside of this object which makes my task become much easier. Thanks 'hrbrmstr'.